# Not able to create NodeManager.properties file

Tags: oracle, weblogic, obiee

I am trying to install obiee on my windows 7 machine 64 bit. All the steps are successfully executed except the last step while creating domain,it gets failed. Pls help me out as i have tried installing both the type of installation simple as well as enterprise , but both the time getting the same error and i get stuck up at the same step

```
 NMProcess: <Mar 25, 2013 7:21:35 PM> <SEVERE> <Fatal error in node manager server>
            NMProcess: java.lang.NullPointerException
            NMProcess: at java.util.Hashtable.containsKey(Hashtable.java:314)
            NMProcess: at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.initNetworkInfoList(NMServerConfig.java:491)
            NMProcess: at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.getNetworkInfoList(NMServerConfig.java:481)
            NMProcess: at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.getConfigProperties(NMServerConfig.java:545)
            NMProcess: at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.<init>(NMServer.java:154)
            NMProcess: at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.main(NMServer.java:375)
            NMProcess: at weblogic.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:31)
```

Excerpt from nodemanager.log which is created at \common\nodemanager:

```
<Mar 25, 2013 7:21:31 PM> <INFO> <Loading domains file: C:\FusionMW\wlserver_10.3\common\nodemanager\nodemanager.domains>
<Mar 25, 2013 7:21:35 PM> <INFO> <Loading identity key store: FileName=C:/FusionMW/WLSERV~1.3/server\lib\DemoIdentity.jks, Type=jks, PassPhraseUsed=true>
<Mar 25, 2013 7:21:35 PM> <WARNING> <Node manager configuration properties file 'C:\FusionMW\wlserver_10.3\common\nodemanager\nodemanager.properties' not found. Using default settings.>
<Mar 25, 2013 7:21:35 PM> <INFO> <Saving node manager configuration properties to 'C:\FusionMW\wlserver_10.3\common\nodemanager\nodemanager.properties'>
<Mar 25, 2013 7:21:35 PM> <SEVERE> <Fatal error in node manager server>
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Hashtable.containsKey(Hashtable.java:314)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.initNetworkInfoList(NMServerConfig.java:491)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.getNetworkInfoList(NMServerConfig.java:481)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.getConfigProperties(NMServerConfig.java:545)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.<init>(NMServer.java:154)
at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.main(NMServer.java:375)
at weblogic.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using the Software only Install mode. When you're saying that you've tried both the installation types, I suppose you're trying to install OBIEE 11.1.1.4 or less.

Software only install mode came in 11.1.1.5 and above. And this helped me overcome the same problem you've stated.

Vijay.